# Excel loop comparing two columns

Tags: excel, vba

I have two sheets.
sheet1:

[image]

And sheet 2:

[image]

I have saved every column to an Array()
so i have 8 different Arrays.

What i need to do is to go though each line in column "A" in sheet1 and see if there is a match in column "A" in sheet2.
If there is a match i need to check the value in column "B" in sheet1 and see if there is a fill in sheet2.
for example if (sheet1) "B2" = "Alder" i need (sheet2) "B8" <> 0.

```
 count = 1
 Do While (count < 2000)
  If (Array1(count) <> "") Then
    count = 1
    Do While (count < 2000)
      If (Array1(count) = Array2(countm) Then
        '' check the value in column "B" in sheet1 and see if there is a fill in sheet2. 
        
      End If
      countm = countm + 1
    Loop
  End If
  count = count + 1
 Loop
```

I hope this makes sense.

Answer (score -1):

You can use a simple formula to achieve this:

```
=INDEX(Sheet2!A:C,MATCH($A2,Sheet2!$A:$A,0),MATCH($B2,Sheet2!$1:$1,0))
```

Put this in column C2 in Sheet1

Since you want VBA, put this in your code.

Remember to change the cell references as per your need

```
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C2:C3").Cells.FormulaR1C1 = "=INDEX(Sheet2!C[-2]:C,MATCH(RC1,Sheet2!C1,0),MATCH(RC2,Sheet2!R1,0))"
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C2:C3") = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C2:C3").Value
```

Comment: I would prefer doing this in VBA, since this is in the middle of my workflow.

Comment: I have posted the VBA solution as well.